# Can XmlTextReader tell the difference between <tag> and <tag />

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, xmltextreader

I am reading an XML file using an XMLTextReader. Is there a way to tell the difference between a start tag (like `<tag>`) and a self-terminating tag (like `<tag />`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement.aspx) property

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the difference between `<tag></tag>` and `<tag />`, then the answer is no, as both are equivalent in XML, and you should not depend on this in your code.